# Why isn't assembly trimming the default when building an ASP.NET docker image?

Tags: asp.net, docker

It is possible to greatly reduce the size of an ASP.Net Docker image by using assembly trimming and by using runtime-deps image as apposed to the aspnet image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore -r linux-musl-x64 /p:PublishReadyToRun=true

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0-alpine-amd64
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./aspnetapp"]
```

In this example, the sample app image is reduced from 220MB to 82.8 MB.

My question is why isn't this the default? What is the benefit of including all those unused assemblies?

Comment: "Why does product/platform/framework/library [not] do this?"-type questions can only really be answered by the original authors - so your question will be better-asked on the `dotnet` GitHub repos, rather than here.